# Google Colab revision history were lost

Tags: google-colaboratory

The revisions I made in a google Colab virtual notebook all disappeared from past three days (I can still find older revision history before these missing 3 days). I can still see in history that I edited the file yesterday, but very strange no revision versions from any of past three days. Any way I can rescue code that I wrote in past three days?
To be clearer, the current version I can see was from 3 days ago, any modification I made in past 3 days were gone, and no history can be found, except the editing history says I edited the file. Again，in short, my recently changed code all lost, anyway I can rescue...

Answer (score 4):

Revision history is by default not permanent.

If you want to save a revision permanently, select

```
MENU > File > Save and pin revision
```

For older revisions in history, you can click on it and select

```
Name this revision
```

To keep it from being deleted.

Comment: I have all revision history from before 3 days ago, only missing ones between 3 days ago and today.

Comment: It will be deleted someday, depending on algorithms. You need to pin, or name it to avoid deletion.

Comment: In short, my recently changed code from past 3 days all lost, anyway I can rescue...

Comment: @MeiNanZhu you seem to be very frustrated. But my guess is No. People can only help with what they know. They mostly don't work for google, and can not change the software.

Comment: @MeiNanZhu  any solution?  I lost my code too